# How do I change the formatting of the data series labels in a Crystal Reports bar chart?

Tags: charts, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

My data series in my bar charts are an amount for every day in the month, and for every month in the year. Crystal insists on labelling each data point with a full date, i.e. yy/MM/dd. For the month chart I want dd/MM and for the year chart I want MM/yy. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

All three options are based on this formula:

```
ToText({Employee.Hire Date},"MM/yy")
```

1. If you've grouped a date field and the chart is in the report-header section, change the group-name calculation to use this formula (Change Group... | Options | Customize Group Name | Use a formula as Group Name)
2. If you are using the 'Advanced' layout, create a formula field (using text above), add this formula field in the chart's "On change of" list.
3. If you've based  your chart on a cross-tab, create a formula field (using text above), add this formula field to the Rows list.